# How to create XPT file from CSV using R

Tags: r, csv

How can we read a CSV file and input the data into write.[xport](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/SASxport/versions/1.5.3/topics/write.xport)() function in R?

Here am mainly confused with converting the csv data that I read to input the write.xport() functionality. I just started learning R.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example of reading a CSV file, using the Baltimore City Employee Salary data.

```
#
# City of Baltimore 2016 employee salary data
#

theFile <- "https://data.baltimorecity.gov/api/views/65ac-s4v5/rows.csv?accessType=DOWNLOAD"

download.file(theFile,
              "./data/baltimoreEmployeeSalaries2016.csv",
              method="wininet", # for Windows, use "curl" for OS X / Linux
              mode="w")

salaries <- read.csv("./data/baltimoreEmployeeSalaries2016.csv",header=TRUE,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
head(salaries)
```

...and the output.

```
> head(salaries)
                   Name                      JobTitle AgencyID                        Agency               HireDate
1      Aaron,Patricia G Facilities/Office Services II   A03031      OED-Employment Dev (031) 10/24/1979 12:00:00 AM
2         Aaron,Petra L    ASSISTANT STATE'S ATTORNEY   A29045 States Attorneys Office (045) 09/25/2006 12:00:00 AM
3        Abbey,Emmanuel         CONTRACT SERV SPEC II   A40001     M-R Info Technology (001) 05/01/2013 12:00:00 AM
4  Abbott-Cole,Michelle        Operations Officer III   A90005           TRANS-Traffic (005) 11/28/2014 12:00:00 AM
5    Abdal-Rahim,Naim A   EMT Firefighter Suppression   A64120         Fire Department (120) 03/30/2011 12:00:00 AM
6 Abdelmeguid,Shahrazad         CONTRACT SERV SPEC II   A29010 States Attorneys Office (010) 11/30/2015 12:00:00 AM
  AnnualSalary  GrossPay
1    $56705.00 $54135.44
2    $75500.00 $72445.87
3    $60060.00 $59602.58
4    $70000.00 $59517.21
5    $64365.00 $74770.82
6    $40019.00 $16283.26
>
```

At this point you can use `write.xport(salaries,...)` to generate a SAS export file.